# Can we write e2e tests of a app having Next JS API in testcafe?

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

Our app is in React + NextJS. Framework is like (Browser code -> (Making call to)->Next JS Api->(Making call  to)->External Rest API). I want to perform E2E Testing using Testcafe where I will mock only the External API call. How can we achieve the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can write E2E tests using testcafe. It simulates actual user experience and interact with your website. It is not dependent underlying tech stack. You just need to host your app and provide the url to testcafe config. Use regular css selectors to pick page elements and make assertions. You can also intercept API requests and use mock data for API. Mocking is not recommended for E2E testing.

Sample code for API response:

```
import { RequestLogger } from 'testcafe'

const logger= RequestLogger(['Domain URLs Array'], {
 logResponseHeader: true,
 logResponseBody: true
})

fixture(`description`).page('app url').requestHooks(logger)

test('description', async () => {

 const domain1Res = logger.requests[0].response
 const domain1ResStr = domain1Res.body.toString()
 const domain1ResJson = domain1ResStr.length ? JSON.parse(domain1ResStr) : null

 // domain1ResJson is the API response object, use it in assertions

})
```

Comment: I want to mock External API response as my data will expire in every 15days and we will get error response. But the issue I am facing with mocking is I am not able to mock the external API using Request Hooks. Although I can mock the NextJS API. But I do not want to mock Next JS API as rest of the code which is calling the External API will not be tested as part of E2E testing. Please suggest how to do the same?

Comment: I think request hooks will work for browser requests, the second level of request i.e. from nextjs to rest server is not seen by testcafe. I would suggest to use unit tests there. If data expires in 15 days, you can also use request hook to save API response in a variable at run time and use those dynamic values for assertions instead of fixed values.

Comment: Okay Thanks. I am writing Unit tests using Jest for the second level of request. I was just wondering if we can achieve by any ways both level of request by testcafe :)

Comment: Can you please post any example how to save the API response in runtime?

Comment: To mock desired requests in your TestCafe tests, you can use `RequestMock`. Please check the documentation: our [guide](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402842/guides/intermediate-guides/intercept-http-requests#mock-http-requests) and [API reference](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402667/reference/test-api/requestmock).